# Table resizing taking too long

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
For Each Table In ActiveDocument.Tables 
    Table.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
Next Table
```

Here is my code for resizing all tables in a word document. Then I put a border around them...

```
For Each Table In ActiveDocument.Tables
With Table
    .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
End With
Next Table
```

About half way down the list of tables, the tables are not re-sized before the box is drawn. 
Its almost like the re-sizing of the tables is taking an excessive amount of time... any ideas?

Comment: Try put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at top then `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of your code.

Comment: Hi PatricK, yes I have that at the beginning and the end of my code... it doesn't make a difference for some reason... any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you save your file in your VBA code before you draw your lines, it will give ample time to resize the tables.